# C#, Xamarin ошибка System.IO.FileNotFoundException при XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)

Tags: c#, xamarin

Код который у меня, ошибка на последней строчке

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("yml.xml"),Encoding.Unicode))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);
```

Ошибка: 
`Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`

содержание переменной content на момент ошибки:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UNICODE\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM \"shops.dtd\">\n<yml_catalog date=\"2010-04-01 17:00\">\n    <shop>\n        <name>Magazin</name>\n        <company>Magazin</company>\n        <url>http://www.magazin.ru/</url>\n\n        <currencies>\n            <currency id=\"RUR\" rate=\"1\" plus=\"0\"/>\n        </currencies>\n\n        <categories>\n            <category id=\"1\">Оргтехника</category>\n            <category id=\"10\" parentId=\"1\">Принтеры</category>\n            <category id=\"100\" parentId=\"10\">Струйные принтеры</category>\n            <category id=\"101\" parentId=\"10\">Лазерные принтеры</category>\n\n            <category id=\"2\">Фототехника</category>\n            <category id=\"11\" parentId=\"2\">Фотоаппараты</category>\n            <category id=\"12\" parentId=\"2\">Объективы</category>\n\n            <category id=\"3\">Книги</category>\n            <category id=\"13\" parentId=\"3\">Детективы</category>\n            <category id=\"14\" parentId=\"3\">Художественная литература</category>\n            <category id=\"15\" parentId=\"3\">Учебная литература</category>\n            <category id=\"16\" parentId=\"3\">Детская литература</category>\n\n            <category id=\"4\">Музыка и видеофильмы</category>\n            <category id=\"17\" parentId=\"4\">Музыка</category>\n            <category id=\"18\" parentId=\"4\">Видеофильмы</category>\n\n            <category id=\"5\">Путешествия</category>\n            <category id=\"19\" parentId=\"5\">Туры</category>\n            <category id=\"20\" parentId=\"5\">Авиабилеты</category>\n\n            <category id=\"6\">Билеты на мероприятия</category>\n        </categories>\n\n        <local_delivery_cost>300</local_delivery_cost>\n\n        <offers>\n            <offer id=\"12341\" type=\"vendor.model\" bid=\"13\" cbid=\"20\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14344</url>\n                <price>15000</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">101</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/device14344.jpg</picture>\n                <delivery>true</delivery>\n                <local_delivery_cost>300</local_delivery_cost>\n                <typePrefix>Принтер</typePrefix>\n                <vendor>НP</vendor>\n                <vendorCode>Q7533A</vendorCode>\n                <model>Color LaserJet 3000</model>\n                <description>A4, 64Mb, 600x600 dpi, USB 2.0, 29стр/мин ч/б / 15стр/мин цв, лотки на 100л и 250л, плотность до 175г/м, до 60000 стр/месяц </description>\n                <manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>\n                <country_of_origin>Япония</country_of_origin>\n            </offer>\n\n            <offer id=\"12342\" type=\"book\" bid=\"17\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14345</url>\n                <price>100</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">13</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/book14345.jpg</picture>\n                <delivery>true</delivery>\n                <local_delivery_cost>300</local_delivery_cost>\n                <author>Александра Маринина</author>\n                <name>Все не так. В 2 томах. Том 1</name>\n                <publisher>ЭКСМО - Пресс</publisher>\n                <series>А. Маринина - королева детектива</series>\n                <year>2009</year>\n                <ISBN>978-5-699-23647-3</ISBN>\n                <volume>2</volume>\n                <part>1</part>\n                <language>rus</language>\n                <binding>70x90/32</binding>\n                <page_extent>288</page_extent>\n                <description>Все прекрасно в большом патриархальном семействе Руденко. Но — увы! — впечатление это обманчиво: каждого из многочисленных представителей семьи обуревают свои потаенные страсти и запретные желания.</description>\n                <downloadable>false</downloadable>\n            </offer>\n\n            <offer id=\"12343\" type=\"audiobook\" bid=\"17\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14346</url>\n                <price>200</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">14</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/book14346.jpg</picture>\n                <author>Владимир Кунин</author>\n                <name>Иваnов и Rабинович, или Аj'гоу ту 'Хаjфа!</name>\n                <publisher>1С-Паблишинг, Союз</publisher>\n                <year>2009</year>\n                <ISBN>978-5-9677-0757-5</ISBN>\n                <language>ru</language>\n                <performed_by>Николай Фоменко</performed_by>\n                <performance_type>начитана</performance_type>\n                <storage>CD</storage>\n                <format>mp3</format>\n                <recording_length>45m23s</recording_length>\n                <description>Перу Владимира Кунина принадлежат десятки сценариев к кинофильмам, серия книг про КЫСЮ и многое, многое другое.</description>\n                <downloadable>true</downloadable>\n            </offer>\n\n            <offer id=\"12344\" type=\"artist.title\" bid=\"11\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14347</url>\n                <price>450</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">17</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/cd14347.jpg</picture>\n                <delivery>true</delivery>\n                <artist>Pink Floyd</artist>\n                <title>Dark Side Of The Moon, Platinum Disc</title>\n                <year>1999</year>\n                <media>CD</media>\n                <description> Dark Side Of The Moon, поставивший мир на уши невиданным сочетанием звуков, — это всего-навсего девять треков, и даже не все они писались специально для альбома. Порывшись по сусекам, участники Pink Floyd мудро сделали новое из хорошо забытого старого — песен, которые почему-либо не пошли в дело или остались незаконченными. Одним из источников вдохновения стали саундтреки для кинофильмов, которые группа производила в больших количествах.</description>\n            </offer>\n\n            <offer id=\"12345\" type=\"artist.title\" bid=\"56\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14348</url>\n                <price>400</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">18</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/dvd14348.jpg</picture>\n                <delivery>true</delivery>\n                <title>Свадьба Мюриэл</title>\n                <year>1999</year>\n                <media>DVD</media>\n                <starring>Тони Колетт (Toni Collette), Рэйчел Грифитс (Rachel Griffiths)</starring>\n                <director>П Дж Хоген</director>\n                <originalName>Muriel's wedding</originalName>\n                <country>Австралия</country>\n                <description>Гадкий утенок из провинциального городка покидает свое гнездо, и в компании своей подруги отправляется искать веселой жизни в большой и загадочный город. Фильм о мечтах и реальности, дружбе и юности молодой девушки, приключения которой повторяют судьбы Золушки и героини Джулии Робертс из ставшего классикой фильма Красотка...</description>\n            </offer>\n\n            <offer id=\"12346\" type=\"tour\" bid=\"71\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14349</url>\n                <price>30000</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">19</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/travel14349.jpg</picture>\n                <delivery>false</delivery>\n                <local_delivery_cost>300</local_delivery_cost>\n                <worldRegion>Африка</worldRegion>\n                <country>Египет</country>\n                <region>Хургада</region>\n                <days>7</days>\n                <dataTour>01/06/2014</dataTour>\n                <dataTour>08/06/2014</dataTour>\n                <name>Hilton</name>\n                <hotel_stars>5*****</hotel_stars>\n                <room>SNG</room>\n                <meal>ALL</meal>\n                <included>авиаперелет, трансфер, проживание, питание, страховка</included>\n                <transport>Авиа</transport>\n                <description>Отдых в Египте.</description>\n            </offer>\n\n            <offer id=\"12347\" type=\"event-ticket\" bid=\"13\" available=\"true\">\n                <url>http://magazin.ru/product_page.asp?pid=14350</url>\n                <price>5000</price>\n                <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>\n                <categoryId type=\"Own\">6</categoryId>\n                <picture>http://magazin.ru/img/tickets14350.jpg</picture>\n                <delivery>true</delivery>\n                <local_delivery_cost>300</local_delivery_cost>\n                <name>Дмитрий Хворостовский и Национальный филармонический оркестр России. Дирижер — Владимир Спиваков.</name>\n                <place>Московский международный Дом музыки</place>\n                <hall plan=\"http://magazin.ru/img/mmdm_plan.jpg\">Большой зал</hall>\n                <hall_part>Партер р. 1-5</hall_part>\n                <date>2014-12-31T19:00</date>\n                <is_premiere>0</is_premiere>\n                <is_kids>0</is_kids>\n                <description>Концерт Дмитрия Хворостовского и Национального филармонического оркестра России под управлением Владимира Спивакова.</description>\n            </offer>\n        </offers>\n\n    </shop>\n</yml_catalog>\n"
```

Я раньше с xml не сталкивался и мб вопрос глупый, но нигде не нашел решения, мб ошибка где-то в самом файле?

файл тестовый, брал [отсюда](http://partner.market.yandex.ru/pages/help/YML.xml) и переформатировал в Unicode, так как русские буквы не считывались, если подскажите как правильно прочитать я буду очень благодарен

Только что попробовал вставить строчку напрямую в переменную content и выдало ту же ошибку, значит проблема в самом тексте xml, но где и почему?

Comment: `Только что попробовал вставить строчку напрямую в переменную content и выдало ту же ошибку` - сделал то же самое, ошибку не выдало. Ну и как бы `FileNotFoundException` вам ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: ну как бы в данном случае нет, ибо файл есть и он отлично читается и заносится в переменную content, а LoadXml не может обработать эту строчку

Comment: Я ж пишу, скопипастил ваш код, взял ваш XML - ничего не падает

Comment: я понял, что у вас не падает, но у меня же падает)

Comment: В общем не знаю что не так с xmlDocument, но взяв вместо него XDocument подключив в ссылках System.Xml.Linq всё отлично заработало

Comment: хм, хотя... я то это делал на полном фреймворке, а не в хсамарине, в этом может быт дело. В общем, может кто с нужными инструментами под рукой сможет повторить